# go up to a specific database version in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

How do I go up to a specific database version from an empty database in rails?

in my case, I did reset the whole database recently, so all tables have been already dropped.

my migration files are as follows:

```
20111127152636_create_users.rb
20120110100458_create_cars.rb
20120131003026_add_birth_date_to_users.rb
```

what command do I have to call to get me the second latest version, which is 20120110100458 ?

I have tried "rake db:migrate:up version=20120110100458".
unfortunately, it didn't get me the result I expected it should be; no tables were created at all.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to run the 2 first migrations, use

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20120110100458
```

(it will run `20111127152636_create_users.rb` and `20120110100458_create_cars.rb`)